# Redis autorestarting on windows subsystem ubuntu

Tags: redis

I am trying to close the redis process on windows subsystem.
When I initially start windows subsystem and use  `ps -ef | grep redis` command, I get the following processes.

```
redis       1648       1  2 20:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
ahmed       1654     361  0 20:55 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

when I kill the redis process, it automatically spawns again on a different port. Here is what I get right now.

```
redis       1682       1  4 21:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
ahmed       1688     361  0 21:10 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

I want to know how to end this process without it respawning again.